# org.testng.TestNGException: An error occurred while instantiating class tests.LoginTests. Check to make sure it can be instantiated

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I've seen this issue here but after reviewing some of the issues I'm just getting confused. I'm trying to setup so that the driver can be passed into tests are they're made. It was throwing a null pointer exception after it opened the browser but then I added this:

```
public LoginTests(WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver ;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

which has been met with the current issue

org.testng.TestNGException:
An error occurred while instantiating class tests.LoginTests. Check to make sure it can be instantiated
at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:134)
at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:25)
at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:30)
at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:112)
at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:165)
at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:122)
at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:102)
at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:94)
at org.testng.TestClass.(TestClass.java:59)
at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
at org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:223)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:55)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:659)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:107)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

BaseClass

```
package pages;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class BaseClass {
    
    protected static WebDriver driver;

        /**
         * This function will execute before each Test tag in testng.xml
         * @param browser
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @BeforeTest
        @Parameters("browser")
        public void setup(String browserName) {
            Reporter.log("********* Browser Session Starter *********");
            if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
            //create firefox instance
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
            else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
                //set path to chromedriver.exe
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
                //create chrome instance
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            //Check if parameter passed as 'Edge'
                    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")){
                        //set path to Edge.exe
                        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","/usr/local/bin/msedgedriver");
                        //create Edge instance
                        driver = new EdgeDriver();
                    }
            
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            //driver.close();
            
        }
        
}
```

Test I'm trying to get working

```
package tests;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pages.BaseClass;
import pages.LoginPage;

public class LoginTests extends BaseClass{
    
    public LoginTests(WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver ;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    
    LoginPage login = new LoginPage();
//  @Test
//  public void testLoginMethod() throws Exception {
//      login.driverInit("chrome");
//      
//      
//  }
    @Test
    @Parameters ("browser")
    public void testTestNG() throws Exception {
    
        login.loginURL();
        
    }
    
}
```

LoginPage if needed:

```
package pages;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Reporter;


public class LoginPage extends BaseClass{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    public void loginURL() {
        driver.get("www.google.com");
        
    
    }

}
```

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RemoteLock</groupId>
  <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

 


</dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"BaseClass" seems okay, rest are mixed up and you need to make some changes in rest like:

"LoginPage":

```
public class LoginPage extends BaseClass{

//constructor with driver as argument
public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {

    this.driver = driver ;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); //initialize the objects
}

 // pageObjects of Login page
   @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "yes")
   WebElement rdoYes;

 // methods of Login page    
   public void loginURL() {
   driver.get("www.google.com");
    
}
```

"Test"

```
public class LoginTests extends BaseClass{

   //Test Method
    @Test
   public void testTestNG() throws Exception {
    //create objects of the required classes with driver as argument
    LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);

    login.loginURL();
    
}   
   }
```

**Checked running the code locally, it's working fine.

Comment: Thank you! I've copied this in and it's saying that ```LoginPage login = new LoginPage(); ``` constructor is undefined. It wants me to pass in null? ```LoginPage login = new LoginPage(null); ```?

Comment: @K White please refer to the updated code, one has to pass- "driver" as argument in the objects of the pages like    LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);